# iBeacon app - receiving data from Iphone/Ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am Developing App which can Turn ON/OFF iBeacon Bluetooth Device. This is Posible to Receive data from iBeacon to Phone/Pad. But Is it posible to iBeacon to Receive data from Phone to Turn ON/OFF. or is there any way to Turn ON/OFF from my Iphone. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

**There is no standard way to do this** that will work with all iBeacons.  The iBeacon standard specifies only how a BLE beacon device transmits, and how receiving mobile devices should interpret the signal.

Different beacon manufacturers have created proprietary ways of configuring their beacons -- typically changing their identifiers but some also allow turning them on and off.  Some manufacturers allow use of Bluetooth LE GATT communications to remotely control these beacons.  This would do what you want.

However, it is important to reiterate that this is not part of the standard.  **If you want to do this, you must choose a beacon vendor that supports this and your app will only work with those beacons.**